# Powershell email attachment charset

Tags: excel, email, csv, powershell, attachment

I am dealing with this problem. 
I have csv file, which is parsed by powershell script. Powershell creates emails with attachment and use smtp server to send it.

The problem is, when user gets email, opens it and wants to open attachment. It's *.csv attachment and it's opened by Excel (tried different versions). It shows corrupted charset (chars like ě é á ý). 
If I open file in Notepad++, I can see that format is set to UTF8 without BOM. If I convert it to UTF8 with BOM, excel can open it with no problem.

My problem is, that I don't know where and if it's possible to force creating attachment with BOM.

String data are read from csv file like this:

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($inputFile)
$data = $reader.ReadLine()
$stringData = {parse, copy, clear $data}
```

Attachment is created like this:

```
$Utf8WithBom = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($True)    
[Byte[]]$contentAsBytes = $Utf8WithBom.GetBytes("$stringData")
$memoryStream.Write($contentAsBytes, 0, $contentAsBytes.Length)

$contentType = New-Object Net.Mime.ContentType -Property @{
    MediaType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
    CharSet = "UTF-8"
    Name = $AttachmentName
}

$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment $attPath, $contentType
$attEmail.Attachments.Add($attachment)
```

Comment: I changed output to HTMl instead CSV

Answer (score 0):

If the Attachment file has no BOM, and even with UTF8Encoding, the BOM does not get written. You have to first change the file from without BOM to with BOM then do the attachment.

To change the encoding from without BOM to with BOM of Attachment File use

```
(Get-Content -path "c:\temp\test.txt" -Encoding UTF8) | 
      Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Path "c:\temp\test.txt"
```

Comment: I cannot access the file. It's created automatically from stream/ I don't want to save a lot of files to drive, send them and then delete. It's waste of time

Comment: what is the reason of error I have provided you and the way to do that is provided either change the output of auto process or save the file, as such you have to opt for one thing as all methods i knows don't change the input from withou bom to bom